# Headless Setup of Asus Tinker Board S

Tags: ssh, headless, asus

I am trying to set up Tinker Board headlessly as I don't have access to a wired keyboard and mouse.

One method I know that works for Raspi is by creating an **SSH file** while setting it up and a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file to provide wifi details. I have flashed the latest Tinker OS v2.2.9 onto the eMMC present on the board as per the instructions. But, in this case I am not able to access the drive once flashed (Contrary to raspi setup).

Is there a way to set it up headlessly?

Thank you for taking out time to read this and helping out.